# Rapid Fire Through UI Buttons issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter link description here](https://prntscr.com/lnafdv)since i'm a newbie i'm having a issue with ui buttons logic the problem is if i simpy use the statment if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")) in the Update statement everything is working fine means the enemy is taking the damage on the continuous firing but when i convert this to a (public function Fire ) so i can use through a Ui fire button using " event trigger " for an andriod platform then the problem occurs that enemy is not taking any damage on continous firing

here's the code and the picture of how i'm implementing through UI in the inspector

```
      function Update(){

          if(firing==true){
         Fire();
      }

           }



       public function Fire(){


         firing=true;


    if(AK47Ammo.CurrentAmmo>=1)

    {
            if(Firing==0)
        {
        AK47Firing();
        }
            }
        }


 public function notFiring(){
 firing=false;
  }



function AK47Firing()
{
        nextFire=Time.time+fireRate;

        anim.SetBool("Fire",true);

    AK47Ammo.CurrentAmmo -= 1;


        gunSound.Play();
        Flash.SetActive(true);
    (MuzzleOff());
        var hitShot:RaycastHit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)*100,hitShot))
        {

  hitShot.transform.SendMessage("DeductPoints",DamageAmount,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver );    
        }                
}

         function MuzzleOff()
        {
                                   Firing=1;

            yield WaitForSeconds(0.2);
            Firing=0;
            var ps: ParticleSystem = GetComponent.<ParticleSystem>();
         ps.Stop();
        Flash.SetActive(false);
                    Shell.SetActive(false); 
        }
```

Comment: Your code indentation is awful. You should fix it. Your problem is probably here: `if(firing==true)`. The only thing that sets that variable to true is the function that's only called if that variable is already true.

Comment: @Draco18s what's the solution to this ? i'm not a professional i'm a student and doing my final year project so i don't know much about this i'll be very thankful if you can help

Comment: because if(firing== true ) and false are being used for rapid firing and the rapid firing still gets start when i press the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the syntax in javascript, but you probably need to make a method that flips firing from true to false on the event trigger. Like so:

```
public void AutoFireToggle()
{
    firing = !firing;
}
```

Note that it works both ways, so it can go from true to false or false to true with this same method.